# Not getting results from IHP DataSync despite setting Row Level Policy

Tags: haskell, ihp

I want to use DataSync on my current application, using IHP 0.16. I believe I have followed all the installation steps in FrontController and Routes.

I have a `characters` table with a `user_id` column connected to the `users` table. I have set the policy on the `characters` table resulting in this generated SQL:

```sql
CREATE POLICY "Users can manage their characters" ON characters USING (user_id = ihp_user_id()) WITH CHECK (user_id = ihp_user_id());
ALTER TABLE characters ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

Trying to run this in the JavaScript console

```js
await query("characters").fetch()
```

I get this error in JavaScript output:

[image]

And this error in IHP output:

```sh
Query (2.119753ms): "SELECT relrowsecurity FROM pg_class WHERE oid = ?::regclass" ["characters"]
Query (0.111442ms): "SET LOCAL ROLE ?" [Identifier {fromIdentifier = "ihp_authenticated"}]
Query (0.130888ms): "SET LOCAL rls.ihp_user_id = ?" Only {fromOnly = Just 0d7b46b1-bcb4-46a2-bf77-ad27dace8416}
FormatError {fmtMessage = "1 single '?' characters, but 3 parameters", fmtQuery = "SELECT ? FROM ??", fmtParams = ["*","characters",""]}
```

This seems to be another error than the row level security error in the DataSync tutorial in the IHP docs. Any idea on what causes this error?

Comment: It was a bug with nullable values and has now been solved by the newest IHP build, so problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in IHP v0.16.0. [It's already fixed in master](https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/commit/61f716d90a01f52e37ff649e15857b5097f1bb01)

It's best to use IHP DataSync with the version mentioned in the introduction text at https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/realtime-spas.html :)

There's btw a workaround for the bug if you don't want to upgrade: You always need to specify an order by, like `await query("characters").orderBy('createdAt').fetch()`

Comment: Thank you!  

Seems like there is a different error now after doing this:

```
Query (2.099332ms): "SELECT relrowsecurity FROM pg_class WHERE oid = ?::regclass" ["characters"]
Query (7.7727e-2ms): "SET LOCAL ROLE ?" [Identifier {fromIdentifier = "ihp_authenticated"}]
Query (0.181584ms): "SET LOCAL rls.ihp_user_id = ?" Only {fromOnly = Just 0d7b46b1-bcb4-46a2-bf77-ad27dace8416}
SqlError {sqlState = "42P01", sqlExecStatus = FatalError, sqlErrorMsg = "relation \"characters\" does not exist", sqlErrorDetail = "", sqlErrorHint = ""}
```

Updated,  removed old policy and re-added polciy.

Comment: As commented on my question, the issue I had has now been solved by the latest IHP build. Thanks  @marc-scholten !